# Fast method to find unique binary permutations in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, unique, permutation

I am looking for a very fast method to create unique permutations of binary numbers in Matlab.

For example - In: [0 0 1]

Becomes - Out: [1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1]

This is what I used for now:

```
M = [zeros(1,L),ones(1,up)];
n = numel(M);
k = sum(M);
c = nchoosek(1:n,k);
m = size(c,1);

binary = zeros(m,n);
binary(sub2ind([m,n],(1:m)'*ones(1,up),c)) = 1;
```

This code works fine and delivers the output I expect but it works very slow for `L=16` and larger `up` values.

Is there any hint I could try to improve perfomance for larger values of **L**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a perms function in matlab. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Already tried perms but it is very slow. The doc for perms itself says that it is only practical for vectors with length of 10 or lower. My vectors have length of 18 or larger.

Comment: You should try the FEX `combinator`- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations. While `nchoosek(1:26,10)` took me 19.5 sec., `combinator(26,10,'c')` gave the same result in 0.7 sec.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest and most generic function I've used to list all possible unordered and without repetition permutation is the [vchoosek](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26190-vchoosek) mex function from Jan Simon that can be found in matlab fileexchange.

I hope this helps!